# Laravel inverse one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to connect two models, where the model Event is owned by Agenda on the field 'agenda_id' inside Event, but when i try to call the relationship by using `->with('agenda')` I get the following query using `DB::getQueryLog()`:

```
"select * from agendas where 0 = 1"
```

My Event model:

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'agenda_id',
        'title',
        'start_date',
        'start_time',
        'end_date',
        'end_time',
        'all_day',
        'description',
        'created_by',
        'tenant_id'
    ];

    public function agenda()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Agenda::class, 'agenda_id');
    }
}
```

My Agenda model:

```php
class Agenda extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'icon',
        'created_by',
        'tenant_id'
    ];

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
    }
}
```

The eloquent query i am trying to use:

```php
$events = Event::with('agenda')->get(['id', 'title', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_date', 'end_time']);
```

Example of what those tables look like:

Events:
[image: Table Events]

Agendas:
[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to bring events with the parent agenda.
I think the function with() works by bringing in child entities. Check it out. 
At first, you don't need to use the function with() if you don't mind that the agenda is loaded with a lazy call $ this-> belongsTo (Agenda :: class, 'agenda_id')

Comment: What is "$this" that you are referring to?

Comment: you can try $events = Event::with('agenda')->get();

Comment: @Roman I'm sorry, i've replaced the line with Event::

Comment: @Abdulmajeed Still doesn't work sadly.

Comment: @MathiasHillmann It seems everything OK to me, you don't need 'agenda_id' in the declaration of relationship, is automatically inferred by Laravel, also can you show the error?

Comment: @Roman Sadly it doesn't have any errors, but when i get the sql (using DB::getQueryLog()) for the eloquent queries it returns "select * from "agendas" where 0 = 1" and the events get a null value where the relationship array should be.

Comment: Try with artisan tinker, see if Event::get() returns something, then Event::with('agenda')->get() should always return something, an empty collections if there are no records, or a collection otherwise.

Comment: @Roman Event::with('agenda')->get(); returns 
"[{"id":4,
"title":"teste",
"start_date":"2020-10-15",
"start_time":"00:00:00",
"end_date":"2020-10-16",
"end_time":"23:59:00",
"start":"2020-10-15T00:00:00",
"end":"2020-10-16T23:59:00",
"agenda":null}]"

Comment: It doesnt return all the fields, check the following, agendas table name should be agendas, and its id field type should be the same as of agenda_id, i.e.: bigint(20) unsigned both fields.

Comment: @Roman Thank you for your help, you made me realize that i hadn't called the relationship id (agenda_id) on the get portion.

Comment: That's not the ideal, with Event::with('agenda')->get() it should return the relationship, I use it all the time. Anyway, great you could make it.

Comment: in model Agenda relationship  public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class,'tenant_id','id');
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to call the id of the relationship on the `get([])` portion of the eloquent query for relationships to work.

Code that worked:

```
$events = Event::where('tenant_id', $tenant_id)->whereIn('agenda_id', $agenda_id)->whereBetween('start_date', [$start_date, $end_date])->with('agenda')->get(['id', 'title', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_date', 'end_time', 'agenda_id']);
```